# How to fetch all entities - Nhibernate select n+1 with multi level deep

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fetch, eager-loading

Let's assume I've got these two classes:

```
public class Grandfather
{
     private int Id;
     private int Version;
     private IList<Father> Childrens; 
}

public class Father
{
    private int Id;
    private int Version;
    private IList<double> ChildrensAges;
    private IList<double> ChildrenGradesOnMath;
    private IList<int> ChildrenNumberOfFriends;
}
```

The Mapping files are:

for Grandfather:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
     namespace="Entities" assembly="Entities">
     <class name="Grandfather" table="Grandfather">
     <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
         <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
         <version name="Version" column="Version" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="property"/>
         <bag name="Childrens" table="Childrens" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join" lazy="false">
            <key column="GrandfatherOwnerId"/>
            <one-to-many class="Father"
       </bag>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

for Father:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
     namespace="Entities" assembly="Entities">
     <class name="Father" table="Father">
     <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
         <generator class="assigned" />
     </id>
     <version name="Version" column="Version" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="property"/>
     <list name="ChildrensAges" table="ChildrensAges" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <key column="ChildrensAgesDBId"/>
        <index column="Ordinal"/>
        <element column="Value" type="System.Double"/>
    </list>
    <list name="ChildrenGradesOnMath" table="ChildrenGradesOnMath" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <key column="ChildrenGradesOnMathDBId"/>
        <index column="Ordinal"/>
        <element column="Value" type="System.Double"/>
    </list>
    <list name="ChildrenNumberOfFriends" table="ChildrenNumberOfFriends" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <key column="ChildrenNumberOfFriendsDBId"/>
        <index column="Ordinal"/>
        <element column="Value" type="System.Int"/>
    </list>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to fetch **all** Grandfathers from the DB.
When I use the query (on DB with 10,000 grandfathers, each grandfather has one child):

```
IList queryEntities = session.CreateQuery("from Grandfather").List();
```

It generates 10,000*5 queries and it takes too much time.

What is the best way to fetch all the data (I need it all so it have to be eager) in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Use FetchMany

something like the following

```
var grandfathers = (from grin session.Query<Grandfather>()
            select gr)
            .FetchMany(f => f.Childrens)
            .ThenFetch(fc = > fc.ChildrensAges)
            .ToList();
```

and you might extend this to ThenFetch or ThenFetchMany to get items on Father.

Comment: When I'm using this solution it's works well for one list in the "Father" class but how can I extend this solution to also include the other lists.

Comment: you should be able to extend for all collections, though reading your model would it make sense to have Children entities rather than these lists?  Each child having Age, Grade and Number of friends.  Currently it's not clear what ages relate to which grades etc.

Comment: tnx, the "children" was just an example of other situation i have when I need 3 kind of list without any relation between them (maybe childrenAges and childrenNumberOfFreinds are not so good example :-) ) However, I still can't make it work for me. Can you please give an example how to write it with more than one list?

Comment: @reuthvexler updated answer with how FetchMany would be applied which is what I think you are asking for.

Comment: great it works, however I get "grandfathers" with multiple identical "father" entries (for each entry in ChildrenAges list I get an entry in the "father" list . I need to distinct it by the 'fatherID' - is there any distinct command that distinct the result not necessarily by the root of the query?